# Company Name Change itunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My company is going through some major changes and it seems that it's not possible to change the company name (the one displayed above your app in the App Store). I don't want to create a new developer account since I already have successful apps under my current account. There has to be someone at Apple that can help me change my company name.

Any links to where I can go would be great.

Comment: Phone them to kickstart this process and to get better direct answers: https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php

Answer (score 26):

Under Apple's [Account Management FAQ Page](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/account-management.html) it asks you to contact them regarding Company/Organization name updates or changes. Once you contact them, they may ask for related documents and do it at their discretion.

The Contact Form can be found at: https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit.php (Note: You will need to login with your Apple ID to access it)

Comment: Thanks for that! Hilarious that a third part site like this is needed to navigate the labyrinth that is apple but hey makes for fun times.