# Application submitted in iTunes app store. How to change company name

Tags: app-store-connect, mac-app-store, itunes-store

Already application submitted in ITunes app store and it showing in iTunes Eg : ApplicationName by "company name, inc." I need to change it to  ApplicationName by "Company Name, inc." - instead of "company name, inc." ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Company Name Change itunes Connect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421915/company-name-change-itunes-connect)

Answer (score 1):

you don't change this company name. EX. when you submit your app on appstore with bundle id : com.yourcompany.nameapp, the default company name will is yourcompany and you can't change this bundle id(note: if you try to update next version you also can't change it).